# PHPspreadsheet Como puedo agregar comentarios a una celda de Excel

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

Estoy usando la libreria PHPspreadsheet pero no logro agregar comentarios a las celdas.
Este es un fragmento del codigo:

```
function WriteExcel($array){
    $objPHPExcel = new Spreadsheet();
    //GRABAMOS EL ENCABEZADO
    $columna=1; 
    foreach($array[0] as $index => $value ){
        $column = GetColumnLetterExcel($columna);
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValueExplicit($column.'1', $index,\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataType::TYPE_STRING);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getComment($column.'1')->getText()->createTextRun('COMENTARIO DE PRUEBA');
        $columna++;
    }
}
```

El excel se genera bien pero no se ven los comentarios.

Comment: Verifica el valor que se genera al concatenar `$column.'1'` o intenta pasar una posición estática para validar si funciona, por ejemplo `getComment('A1')`.

Comment: Ya lo hice y aún así no se ven los comentarios @DjCrazy

Comment: En vista de que no podemos hacer pruebas aquí directamente, puedes consultar [este recurso](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/dff9880582c4c379ffd4aee7dc62caaab2bab975/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#add-a-comment-to-a-cell) en GitHub, hay un ejemplo completo para insertar comentarios.